# Adding a link to a document library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, document-library, hyperlink

As we all know, you can add documents to a document library (duh). But I was asked if I could create a library where you could add links as well.

I immediately thought it was possible, but I did not fully understand what was being asked. The end user wants a link to appear as a "document" in the library. To try and explain further the link needs to function like a document would. If I click on a document in a library it opens the document and hypothetically if I clicked on a link I would be navigated to the link.

This is not the same as adding a hyperlink column in the document library. They do not want a link associated with a document, but rather a link by itself in the library.

Hopefully, this makes enough sense for someone to provide a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **CAN** add links to a document library. Here is how you do it:

- Go to the document library's settings
- Click on "Advanced Settings"
- Set the "Allow management of content types?" to Yes and click on "OK" at the bottom of the page.
- From the library's settings page, click on the "Add from existing site content types" in the middle of the page.
- From the "Available Site Content Types" section, click on "Link to a Document" and then click on "Add", then "OK"
- Now go to the document library main view. From the ribbon, click on the "New Document" text with the little down arrow beside it.
- You will then see the "Link to a Document" option for adding as many links to your library as you wish, along with regular documents.

**Edit** - Tested on SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016 on-prem. If my memory serves me, I was using "Link to a Document" since SharePoint 2010. I don't remember if SharePoint 2007 had the same thing available.

Comment: well played Glen Totten! learn something new every day :)

Comment: Hi @glen , good tries, but I tried this steps before I Post my answer and I found out it does not match the requirements of OP . the OP said **They do not want a link associated with a document, but rather a link by itself in the library.** and with the content type *Link to Document* mean you must upload your document to can select your content type and add a link , I don't think it matches the requirements of OP, he need to upload documents or links in document library, not document with links , so he said **This is not the same as adding a hyperlink column in the document library**

Comment: So I don't think adding new hyperlink column or use another content type will solve the issue because in any case, you must upload the document !!! So based on my understand I said in my answer *you can't add a Link instead of Document in Document Library.* :) Finally, I would like to thank u for your valuable contributions

Comment: You do not have to upload a document. If you use the "Link to a Document", you get a different dialog box that strictly asks for a document name and a document URL. Once you click on "OK", it basically creates a redirect page (to whatever location you specify in the URL) in the library. You add links by going to the ribbon of the library and clicking on the "New Document" text (with down arrow next to it) rather than the "Upload Document" button in the ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

.url files are blocked by default in SharePoint.  to achieve what you want to achieve you would need to unblock .url files then you can create shortcuts on your desktop to web locations and upload them into your document library.  I haven't tested this but it makes sense in theory.

EDIT
the new library experience in my SP online allows me to create links in document libraries OOTB and by default! dont know how 2010 works with it though.

My understanding on why this is blocked is because someone with know how could create malicious .url files.  That being said they would have to be some kind of hacker to do anything with it.

Comment: Just as a sidenote man some stakeholders have some WEIRD demands.  Personally i would take a step back seperate yourself from the platform and just look at what the business need is and achieve that in a way that doesnt require you to do what i've suggested lol.  Would be much better to make a link list store your links there and then edit the page where the doc library is and add the link list to the top of bottom.  Or better yet make a page and put both web parts on it instead of modding the app page.

Answer (score 1):

**As a short answer:** No, you can't add a Link instead of Document in Document Library.

The `Document Library` is used to store, organize, sync, and share documents not links or data items and uploading or creating a document is amandatory in Document Library.

**As a workaround,** Instead of using Document Library

1. You can create a  `Custom list` with Hyperlink column and optionally attach your document to the list Item.
2. You can create a `Links List` and add the link for both URL and Document URL from Document Library.

   - In this case, you will be able to open your document or naviagte to a specific Link regardless the type of link (aspecific URL or Document URL).